How to convert initial timestamp of each line
Trying to convert initial timetsamp of each line of a log file as follows
$ cat test.log
[Tue Apr  9 03:32:21 2024] {cmd1}
[Tue Apr  9 03:33:42 2024] {cmd2}
[Tue Apr  9 03:35:51 2024] {cmd3}
$
$ cat test.log | < How ?? > 
2024-04-09 03:32:21 cmd1
2024-04-09 03:33:42 cmd2
2024-04-09 03:33:42 cmd3
$

Attempted these options, but no luck
$ cat test.log
[Tue Apr  9 03:32:21 2024] {cmd1}
[Tue Apr  9 03:33:42 2024] {cmd2}
[Tue Apr  9 03:35:51 2024] {cmd3}
$
$ cat test.log | awk -F"[][{}]" '{print $2" "$4}'
Tue Apr  9 03:32:21 2024 cmd1
Tue Apr  9 03:33:42 2024 cmd2
Tue Apr  9 03:35:51 2024 cmd3
$ 
$ cat test.log | awk -F"[][{}]" '{print strftime("%F %T", $2)" "$4}'
1970-01-01 00:00:00 cmd1
1970-01-01 00:00:00 cmd2
1970-01-01 00:00:00 cmd3
$ 

strftime() function returning start of epoch time
$ date -d "Tue Apr  9 03:32:21 2024" +"%s"
1712633541
$ 
$ echo 1712633541 | awk  '{print strftime("%F %T", $0)}'
2024-04-09 03:32:21
$ 

Also tried system() function
$ echo "Tue Apr  9 03:32:21 2024" | awk  '{print strftime("%F %T", system("date -d \"$0\" +\"\%s\""))}'
awk: cmd. line:1: warning: escape sequence `\%' treated as plain `%'
date: invalid date 'sh'
1970-01-01 00:00:01
$ 


Using any awk:
$ awk '{
    split($0,d)
    sub(/[^]]+]./,"")
    mth = (index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",d[2]) + 2) / 3
    printf "%04d-%02d-%02d %s %s\n", d[5], mth, d[3], d[4], $0
}' test.log
2024-04-09 03:32:21 {cmd1}
2024-04-09 03:33:42 {cmd2}
2024-04-09 03:35:51 {cmd3}


Here is a way:
paste -d '\0' \
  <(sed 's/^\[//; s/].*//' test.log | date -f - '+%F %T') \
  <(sed 's/[^]]*]//' test.log)


Addressing OP's issue of the strftime() function not returning the desired date/time string ...
The format of a strftime() call:
strftime( format [, timestamp] )

If timestamp is not provided then the current system time is used; this happens to be the same value as returned by the systime() function - the number of seconds since the system epoch.
In OP's code we see strftime( "%F %T", $2 ) where $2 looks like Tue Apr  9 03:32:21 2024.  While %F %T is a valid format, Tue Apr  9 03:32:21 2024 is not a valid format for the number of seconds since the system epoch.
OP needs to convert Tue Apr  9 03:32:21 2024 into the equivalent number of seconds since the system epoch.  One way to do this is with the mktime() function:
mktime( "YYYY MM DD HH MM SS" )

OP will need to convert the string Tue Apr  9 03:32:21 2024 into the string 2024 4 9 03 32 21.
Modifying OP's current awk script, while borrowing Ed Morton's code to convert Apr to 4:
awk -F"[][{}]" '
{ split($2,d," ")                                                         # split "Tue Apr  9 03:32:21 2024" on spaces; place results in array d[]
  mth = (index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",d[2])+2) / 3        # convert "Apr" to "4"
  gsub(/:/," ",d[4])                                                      # convert "03:32:21: to "03 32 21"
  print strftime("%F %T", mktime(d[5] " " mth " " d[3] " " d[4])), $4     # convert "2024 4 9 03 32 21" to epoch seconds then reformat as "%F %T"
}
' test.log

This generates:
2024-04-09 03:32:21 cmd1
2024-04-09 03:33:42 cmd2
2024-04-09 03:35:51 cmd3

NOTE: see GNU awk (gawk) time functions for more details on the strftime(), systime() and mktime() functions

Perl and Time::Piece to the rescue!
<test.log perl -MTime::Piece -lne '
    /\[(.+)\] \{(.+)\}/;
    print Time::Piece->strptime($1, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
          ->strftime("%F %T"), " $2"'


-n reads the input line by line, runs the code for each line;
-l removes newlines from input and adds them to print;
/\[(.+)\] \{(.+)\}/ matches the input line and remembers the timestamp and command in $1 and $2;
strptime parses the timestamp and strftime formats it to the desired format.

It doesn't give the expected output, though. The last line has the time 03:35:51, not 03:33:42 - but so does the input, so I guess it's a typo.

Given:
$ cat file
[Tue Apr  9 03:32:21 2024] {cmd1}
[Tue Apr  9 03:33:42 2024] {cmd2}
[Tue Apr  9 03:35:51 2024] {cmd3}
[Tue Apr  999 03:35:51 2024] {bad time}
nonsense line

Here is a Ruby:
ruby -r time -lne '
m=/^\[([^\]]+)\]\s+\{([^}]+)\}/.match($_)
t=Time.parse($1) rescue nil
puts "#{t} #{$2}" if m && t
' file 

Prints:
2024-04-09 03:32:21 -0400 cmd1
2024-04-09 03:33:42 -0400 cmd2
2024-04-09 03:35:51 -0400 cmd3

Online demo

You can manually select the time fields if you don't like the default -- which includes the time zone you run it on...

Using jq:
$ jq -sRc 'split("\n")[]|strptime("[%a %b %e %T %Y]")' test.log

[2024,3,9,3,32,21,2,99," {cmd1}"]
[2024,3,9,3,33,42,2,99," {cmd2}"]
[2024,3,9,3,35,51,2,99," {cmd3}"]

$ jq -sRr 'split("\n")[]|strptime("[%a %b %e %T %Y]")|strftime("%F %X") + values[-1]' test.log

2024-04-09 03:32:21 {cmd1}
2024-04-09 03:33:42 {cmd2}
2024-04-09 03:35:51 {cmd3}

taking it further...
here's an example using ps that looks similar to your test.log
$ ps -eo pid,lstart,command

PID                  STARTED COMMAND
  1 Tue Mar 26 00:19:40 2024 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --switched-root --system --deserialize 30
  2 Tue Mar 26 00:19:40 2024 [kthreadd]
  3 Tue Mar 26 00:19:40 2024 [rcu_gp]

ps -eo pid,lstart,command | jq -sRr 'split("\n")[1:-1]
  | map([split("[\\s]+";"x")[]|select(length>0)]
  | { pid: .[0],
      time: .[4],
      cmd: .[6],
      args: .[7:] })'

Output
[
  {
    "pid": "1",
    "time": "00:19:40",
    "cmd": "/usr/lib/systemd/systemd",
    "args": [
      "--switched-root",
      "--system",
      "--deserialize",
      "30"
    ]
  },
  {
    "pid": "2",
    "time": "00:19:40",
    "cmd": "[kthreadd]",
    "args": []
  },
  {
    "pid": "3",
    "time": "00:19:40",
    "cmd": "[rcu_gp]",
    "args": []
  }
]

